# Undefined reference to QIconvCodec during Qt embedded make?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt4, installation

I'm trying to configure my Qt for Embedded Linux with a virtual framebuffer according to [these instructions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvfb.html).  From the Qt for Embedded source folder, I'm trying:

```
./configure -embedded -opensource -confirm-license -verbose -qvfb
make
```

I get the following error which prevents me from doing `make install`:

```
.obj/release-shared-emb-x86/qtextcodec.o: In function `setup()':
qtextcodec.cpp:(.text+0x23cc): undefined reference to `QIconvCodec::QIconvCodec()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.4] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cstjean/qt/src/corelib'
make: *** [sub-corelib-all-ordered] Error 2
```

If I do:

```
./configure -embedded -opensource -confirm-license -verbose -qvfb
make -no-iconv
sudo make install -no-iconv
```

...This works. But when I go into QtCreator, Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions, I try to select qmake for Qt Embedded (for me it's in `/home/cstjean/qt/bin/qmake`) and it tells me:

```
Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install
```

I've tried googling this like crazy.  There are a lot of suggestions to download various libraries, which I've tried to no avail, but perhaps I'm missing something because this is a pretty fresh installation of Ubuntu I'm using.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing Gnome and starting over from scratch for my Qt Embedded for Linux installation.

I googled `gnome for ubuntu 12.04` and found [these instructions](http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/).  You'll have to see which version of Ubuntu you have and search for that of course.  You can see which version you have by typing into a command line:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Once I had gnome installed, I restarted my computer and signed in using Gnome.

Then I completely uninstalled and removed all traces of Qt Embedded:

```
cd yourQtEmbeddedDir
sudo make uninstall
cd ..
rm -r yourQtEmbeddedDir sourceFileTarYouHadDownloaded.tar.gz
```

I redownloaded the source file tar for Qt Embedded for Linux (from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads)) and proceeded to install according to [these instructions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvfb.html) after extracting the source files from the tar:

```
./configure -embedded -opensource -confirm-license -verbose -qvfb
make
sudo make install
```

Now, if you tell QtCreator about `qmake` from this installation, then QtCreator will no longer complain about a bad installation!  Ta da!

*Note:* If you're attempting to the do the Virtual Framebuffer business too, then this is not the end of the road.  You need to have Qt for X11 installed as well in order to compile qvfb.

**Long story short:** You need Gnome if you're trying to install Qt Embedded for Linux with a Virtual Framebuffer on Ubuntu!